# I want to write a code that finds saddle point, local max-min in two variables functions at (a,a)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

[image]

Actually, I want a code that can give all the answers to the question in this exact problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's usually good to show what you've done before posting a question on SE. If you are completely unsure of where to start, I would suggest looking at the `Grad` [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grad.html). There is an example under the "Applications" tab that is very similar to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic task in function analysis. You first find the critical points (Max/main/Saddle) by setting the first derivatives to zero. Then you calculate the hessian matrix (second derivatives) and determine the type using the eigenvalues of the hessian matrix. If all eigenvalues are negative, we have a max., if all eigenvalues are positive, we have a min., if we have pos and neg eigenvalues we have a saddle point. However if we have zero eigenvalues, this criteria can not be applied.

```
f[x_, y_] = x^3 - 3 a x y + y^3;
Solve[{D[f[x, y], x] == 0, D[f[x, y], y] == 0}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

[image]

Well, critical points are: {0,0} and {a,a}

The hessian matrix can be got from a special form of the "D" operator:

```
hess= D[f[x,y],{{x,y},2}];
```

The Eigenvalues are:

```
ev=Eigenvalues[hess]
```

[image]

And if we insert the coordinates of the critical points:

```
ev /. {{x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> a, y -> a}}
```

[image]

Therefore, for {x,y}=={0,0} we have a saddle point. And for {x,y}=={a,a} we have a min.

Comment: Can I ask you to do something more complex? For example, let it output as a table. Let the code you write for each function I put in will show the local max local min and saddle points.

Comment: Daniel, have you started a free homework service?

Comment: @Kadircan GÜNGÖR I think with my comments, you should be able to do it yourself.